# I think i might have accidentally clicked a phishing link, how can i be sure?

Tags: virus, phishing

Long story short I might have accidentaly clicked a phishing link is there any kind of test I can do or anything I can do to check?

Comment: [VirusTotal?](https://www.virustotal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few standard tests / questions to detect phishing:

1. Most serious companies will never ask you for login data by email.
2. Check if the URL is looking strange. (very long / with typo in main domain?)
3. Check for HTTPS connection and look for certificate information and check this (click on the lock in the adress bar). Check if you can find a certificate. Check if the certificate contains data like company's name. If so you're pretty safe.
4. Visit the site normally in another tab, check for green bar in adress bar if so, check if the potential phishing link provides this.
5. Call the company / write an e-mail to confirm this e-mail. (using the adress on default homepage)